# Python: Word search

Tags: python

So I have been trying to come up with a code for a word search solver in python. With this I have been having a problem in a particular section of the code, the section is as follows:

```
first_words=[]
final_words=[]
first_row={}
final_row={}
first_column={}
final_column={}
for x in words:
    for y in x[0]:
        first_words.append(y)
print(first_words)

for x in words:
    for y in x[-1]:
        final_words.append(y)
print(final_words)

for z in rows:     
    for x in first_words:
        if x in rows[rows.index(z)]:
            first_row.update({x:rows.index(z)+1})
print(first_row)

for z in rows:
    for x in final_words:
        if x in rows[rows.index(z)]:
            final_row.update({x:rows.index(z)+1})
print(final_row)

for z in rows:
    for w in z:
        for x in first_words:
            if x in z[z.index(w)]:
                first_column.update({x:z.index(w)+1})
print(first_column)
```

So basically this section takes the first and last letters of a word and then cross checks it on what index the letter appears in the grid. I stored every index in a dictionary. Now my problem is that it seems to read the wrong index. For example for the given words: 'Tea' and 'Sit' the first letter indexes seems to have no problem but the last letter indexes is off since the index of the letter 'T' of 'Tea' is being read instead of the letter 'T' in 'Sit'. How do I fix this? Any help would be highly appreciated!

For visual guide:

```
['mon', 'sit', 'tea'] #words to find
['MON', 'SIT', 'TEA'] #for simplification in error checking I used the same strings to populate my 
                       board
  1 2 3
1 M O N
2 S I T  #The board
3 T E A

['M', 'S', 'T'] #first letter of the words
['N', 'T', 'A'] #last letter of the words
{'M': 1, 'S': 2, 'T': 3} #dictionary for the indexes of the first letter(row)
{'N': 1, 'T': 3, 'A': 3}  #dictionary for the indexes of the last letter(row)
{'M': 1, 'S': 1, 'T': 1}  #dictionary for the indexes of the first letter(column)
{'N': 3, 'T': 1, 'A': 3}  #dictionary for the indexes of the lastletter(column)
words= ['MON', 'SIT', 'TEA']
rows= ['MON', 'SIT', 'TEA']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to do everything at the same time :

```
for x in words:
    for index,y in enumerate(x[0]):
        first_words.append(y)
        first_row.update({y : index+1})
```

Do the same for the rest and it should be fine.
This way is easier and way less prone to errors.